# How to replace a string in a filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to replace a string in a filename:

Original filename:

```
gamename games.com.zip
```

Target filename:

```
gamename.zip
```

I'm trying to replace the string  `games.com` with an empty string. `gamename` is not a constant string it can be anything, but `games.com` is a constant string.

Comment: `rename " games.com" "" *zip`

Comment: Oh, in the file name, no in the body. Right.

Comment: Whats your challenge here to use String.Replace man?

Comment: @Eddy_Em: Bareword "games" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.
Bareword "com" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: Some linux distros have another version of `rename`. E.g., Ubuntu's one has the following syntax: `rename "s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g" *`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
mv "$filename" "${filename/ games.com/}"
```

This is documented under 'Pattern subsitution' in the 'Bash' man-page

Or http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion online

Comment: No need to escape the period; it's a pattern, not a regular expression. The trailing '/' is also optional.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. I'm leaving the trailing `/` for good form (making the idiomatic form of a /pattern/substitution combination visible)

Answer (score 1):

Bash parameter expansion will help:

```
mv "$f" "${f/ games.com}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command:

```
$ filename="gamename games.com.zip"
$ rename " games.com" "" "$filename"
```

Since the name of your zip file has a space you need to make sure you enclose it in double-quotes.

Comment: Thanx, but it won't work as I expected. You see, "gamename" is not a constant string, it can be anything else, so the script will have to be flexible... the only constant string in the filename will be " games.com.zip".